# IPSec over L2TP: key derivation for pre-shared key failed

Tags: networkmanager, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I set up a VPN to my Uni (using IPSec over L2TP) before using ~Ubunutu (GalliumOS), Strongswan, and NetworkManager, but this time I keep getting an error about my PSK, see this log output:

```
Jun 22 11:01:44 charon[6145]: sending packet: from 192.168.1.65[500] to 141.2.54.193[500] (244 bytes)
Jun 22 11:01:44 charon[6145]: received packet: from 141.2.54.193[500] to 192.168.1.65[500] (260 bytes)
Jun 22 11:01:44 charon[6145]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
Jun 22 11:01:44 charon[6145]: key derivation for pre-shared key failed
Jun 22 11:01:44 charon[6145]: generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 522813457 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
Jun 22 11:01:44 charon[6145]: sending packet: from 192.168.1.65[500] to 141.2.54.193[500] (56 bytes)
Jun 22 11:01:44 charon[6145]: establishing connection '358cedab-07d4-49ed-9851-b622f8770710' failed
Jun 22 11:01:44 charon[6145]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
```

I know for certain that the pre-shared key I use is fine. I remember that last time a problem was related to the cyphers. I thus ran the [ike-scan script from the "known issues" site of network-manager-l2tp](https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/wiki/Known-Issues#querying-vpn-server-for-its-ikev1-algorithm-proposals) and got the following output:

```
SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=SHA1 Group=2:modp1024 Auth=PSK LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
SA=(Enc=AES KeyLength=128 Hash=SHA1 Group=19 Auth=PSK LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
SA=(Enc=AES KeyLength=256 Hash=SHA1 Group=20 Auth=PSK LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration(4)=0x00007080)
```

Accordingly, I specified:

- Phase 1 Algorithms: 3des-sha1-modp1024
- Phase 2 Algorithms: 3des-sha1

I believe the problem must lie somewhere here any suggestions is greatly appreciated! (I am running Ubuntu, GalliumOS 2.1, 16.04, xenial, but that was the same when it worked)

Comment: You are getting an INVAL_KE error (i.e invalid PSK). Are you sure the pre-shared key is correct?

Comment: ignore my response, I missed the part where you said you are sure that the PSK is correct.

You could try using libreswan instead. You could do a 'sudo apt install libreswan' to switch to libreswan (and it will automatically uninstall strongswan)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, that didn't change much though :(

Comment: However, what (weirdly did help) was purging and reinstalling strongswan. I have no idea why and I didn't change any of the settings. but somehow that did the trick